# Issue with worksheet object and LoadPicture in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have been working on an excel macro and have come across an issue that doesn't make sense to me.
I have on two of my sheets, (`Sheets("Printing Sheet")` and `Sheets("Printing Sheet B")`, an Xactive image object called slipLogo. I created a subProcedure that should change the image loaded into slipLogo and the color of other cells on the sheet depending on an options selected within a userform. The userfrom also decides which of the two slipLogos and therefore sheets are being changed. But I was having problems with the image changing portion, so I pulled out the troublesome code to do some troubleshooting on it and focused on just one of the two sheets.

The issue is that I get the error "method failing" which points to the slipLogo part of `ws.slipLogo.Picture=LoadPicture(C:Users\Logo.jpg)`. However when I use instead the following line `Sheets("Printing Sheet").slipLogo.Picture=LoadPicture("C:\Users\Logo.jpg")` everything works.
This indicates to me that for some reason `ws` does not equal `Sheets("Printing Sheet")`.

```
Sub Help5()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("Printing Sheet")
Dim imagePath As String
 imagePath = "C:\Users\Logo.jpg"



  ws.slipLogo.Picture = LoadPicture(imagePath)
  
'Sheets("Printing Sheet").slipLogo.Picture = LoadPicture(imagePath)

   With Sheets("Printing Sheet").slipLogo 'the ws also does not work at this location
        .Height = 35
   End With
End Sub
```

Comment: A `Worksheet` variable such as `ws` does not have a `.slipLogo` property.

Comment: Ok, but I need `ws` or something similar for the sub procedure that I have taken this from. I need something that can easily be changed to `Sheets("Printing Sheet")` or `Sheets("Printing Sheet B")` .

Comment: Ok thanks. I did have to add `Set img = ws.Shapes("slipLogo").OLEFormat.Object.Object` to the code. And then write the line `img.Picture=LoadPicture(imagePath)`